# android release key for facebook

Tags: android, facebook, openssl, android-keystore

I know this question has been asked, but I have been trying 500 different ways of generating a release key for my android application so i can use facebook to get data. Reason why is that I want to test it on my own device and the error I get when I try to login using Facebook is " Invalid Key hash" followed by a key hash that I have never even entered.

So what Have I tried to generate the key hash?

I've gone to libs in Java with my command prompt and entered this line:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Riaan\.android | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64
```

androiddebugkey is the keystore alias I got when I exported the file from eclipse, the path to the keystore is the one That I have in `C:users\riaan\.android` , It's called debug.keystore.

then in the next line I define the path to openssl and I do this once again after that.

I do actually get something that looks like a key hash. However when I put it on facebook, I still get the same error I had before. it worked once and than stopped working.

another thing I find curious is that I don't get prompted for a password when I put the line in the command prompt. So it's obvious I am doing something wrong, but what?

for completeness I will give the **code** for the login page here:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import com.facebook.Request;
    import com.facebook.Response;
    import com.facebook.Session;
    import com.facebook.SessionState;
    import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
    import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
    import com.facebook.model.GraphObjectList;
    import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
    import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class User_data_prompt_dialog extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private TextView userInfoTextView;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first_dialog, container, false);

 // create manual input button
    Button manualbutton =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.manualinput);
    manualbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // experiment, erase later.
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ManualDataEntry.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                getActivity().finish();
                // implement soon!
            }
        });

    // initialize authentication button and ask for permissions
    // to access data from facebook.
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes"));

    // Textview that displays data
    userInfoTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);

    return view;
}
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    if (state.isOpened()) {
        userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


}

private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
    StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");

    // Example: typed access (name)
    // - no special permissions required
    userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", 
        user.getName()));

    // Example: typed access (birthday)
    // - requires user_birthday permission
    userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", 
        user.getBirthday()));

    // Example: partially typed access, to location field,
    // name key (location)
    // - requires user_location permission
    userInfo.append(String.format("Location: %s\n\n", 
        user.getLocation().getProperty("name")));

    // Example: access via property name (locale)
    // - no special permissions required
    userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n", 
        user.getProperty("locale")));

    return userInfo.toString();
}

private interface MyGraphLanguage extends GraphObject {
    // Getter for the ID field
    String getId();
    // Getter for the Name field
    String getName();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> here are two type of certificate fingerprint, debug and release.
>
> To display debug certificate fingerprint in window, simple open cmd
>   and type the command:
>
> First check the java path variable.
>
> after command change the user name. keytool -list -v -keystore
>   C:/Users/xxxxx/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
>
> To display release certificate fingerprint, you need to create the
>   release keystore and and sign the .APK once.
>
> 1.simple way to find the sh-1 or md5
>
> Ceration of  the sign apk show the sh-1 or md5 in eclipse.
>
> or
>   2.- open cmd and type the command: keytool -list -v -keystore  -alias
>
> keytool -list -v -keystore C:/release_certificate_name -alias
>   alias_name
>
> where:  is the path and name of the keystore.
>    is alias that you assigned to the certificate when
>   you created it.

also check the [enter link description here](http://androidtechniqe.blogspot.in/)

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is what I should do: 1) do a signed export  of my .APK file. Collect the keystore alias. 2) put this in the command. 3) find the path to the keystore and paste it in the command. 4) find adres of my openssl and paste it in the command. Is that correct?

Comment: i thing no need to use openssl . if my question helpful so plz accept the ans.